# SQLGrammarException when using Hibernate formula with Postgres specific function

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I have an XML Hibernate (3.6.10) mapping with one line which should fill the property duration (type is long) via a formula. The column startTime and endTime is timestamp. From my hbm.xml file:

```
<property name="duration" formula="extract(epoch from(endTime - startTime))" />
```

When I run this within a WebLogic server, the following sql is created for this:

```
select this_.extract(this_.epoch from(this_.endTime - this_.startTime)) 
  as formula4_0_ from MYTABLE this_;
```

This results in the following exception:

```
 nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Why is hibernate not recognizing the (postgres) functions epoch and extract? Why is it adding the table name?
Is there a way to enforce it?

The hibernate dialect is set to "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect".

Thx

EDIT: As a workaround or maybe better solution I will implement the getter method for duration on the java entity side. Hopefully the subtraction won't become a performance bottleneck on the application server. ;) This appears to be more reliable with respect to various db dialects.

Nevertheless it would be interesting how the original problem could be solved with hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`epoch` isn't a function, it's more like a keyword. Though [oddly it doesn't appear on the list of keywords, even as unreserved](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

`extract` isn't PostgreSQL-specific. It's standard SQL. That's why it has the kind of insane syntax only the SQL committee could come up with instead of being written as a sane normal function like `extract('epoch', endtime - starttime)`.

However, the `epoch` unit-specifier *is* a PostgreSQL extension to the SQL-standard `extract`.

Anyway, try:

```
extract('epoch' FROM (endTime - startTime))
```

PostgreSQL lets you write the first term with or without quotes (i.e. as a keyword/identifier or as a literal). Your framework may understand it better if it's phrased as a literal.

Otherwise, [perhaps you'll have more luck with the non-standard `to_char` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(endTime - startTime, 'J');
```

as that's just an ordinary function. It returns a string you'll have to convert to an integer, though, so you may want:

```
SELECT CAST( to_char(endTime - startTime, 'J') AS int4 )
```

... if your ORM doesn't mangle that too.

---

Compatibility of `extract`

- [MySQL supports `EXTRACT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract), but not the `epoch` unit-specifier.
- [Oracle supports `EXTRACT`(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm), but not the `epoch` unit-specifier.
- MS-SQL doesn't appear to support `EXTRACT` and wants you to use `DATEPART` instead.

Comment: When using the quote on epoch keyword hibernate is still adding the table name in front of extract. --> select this_.extract('epoch' from(this_.endTime - this_.startTime)) as formula4_0_ from MYTABLE this_;
I will try your other suggestion and let you know. Thx so far

Comment: Unfortunately the CAST with char pattern 'SSSSMS' also doesn't work. This time hibernate adds the tablename to 'int4'.

Comment: @Wintermute Report a bug against Hibernate. Stupid ORMs. You could try working around it with the PostgreSQL specific syntax `to_char(endTime - startTime, 'J')::int8` and see if mangles that. If it does, you'll have to wrap it all in a simple SQL function to work around the braindead ORM, e.g. `create or replace function extract_epoch(interval) returns int8 as $$ select extract('epoch' from $1) $$ language sql`. Then use that in your code. Of course, you'll have to run the `CREATE FUNCTION` as native SQL to stop Hibernate mangling it.

Comment: If I wrap the call in a function, then it is working with the braindead ORM. ;) Nevertheless this feels a bit like fighting the tool. But as we use PostgreSQL on the development environment we can create functions and use the ORM. Thanks for your help!